# How do you use environment variables inside of Config.groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

Inside of Config.groovy i have setup a few environment variables:

```
def appName = grails.util.Metadata.current.getApplicationName()
def casUrl  = "https://login.cas.server/cas"
environments {
    development {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
        host.address = "12.34.56.78"
        host.port = "8080"
    }
    test {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
        host.address = "http://staging.server.somewhere.com/"
        host.port = ""
    }
    production {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = false
        host.address = "http://www.production.com"
        host.port = ""
    }
 }
```

I'm trying to use those values inside the same configuration file (Config.groovy) like so:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.loginUri = '/login'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.serviceUrl = "${host.address}:${host.port}/${appName}/j_spring_cas_security_check"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.serverUrlPrefix = '${casUrl}'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.proxyCallbackUrl = "/secure/receptor"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.afterLogoutUrl = "${casUrl}/logout?url=${host.address}:${host.port}/${appName}/"
```

However, the only thing that is getting resolved is the appName variable, everything else is null. Is this something that can be done? It looks like it was used in this post here [Grails: Spring Security CAS Working in 2.2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385581/grails-spring-security-cas-working-in-2-2-3-but-not-in-2-3-0?rq=1) but I cant seem to get them to resolve.

If I do something like

```
def appName = grails.util.Metadata.current.getApplicationName()
def casUrl = "https://login.umt.edu/cas"
host.address = "MyAddress"
environments {
...
```

The configSlurper resolves that host.address inside the CAS config, why can't I access the enviornment variables?

Comment: How many `environments`  closure exists in `config.groovy` file. It should be only one.

Answer (score 0):

See the answer [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html) under **Basic Configuration**.

> However, you can't nest after using the dot notation. In other words, this won't work

```
// Won't work!
foo.bar {
    hello = "world"
    good = "bye"
}
```

So try to use nesting like this

```
foo {
   bar {
    hello = "world"
    good = "bye"
   }
}
```

Comment: doing it this way, the variables are still not getting resolved. In my URL is `%5B%3A%5D%3A%5B%3A%5D%2Fmyapplication%2Fj_spring_cas_security_check`

Answer (score 0):

Move the properties that depend on host.address and host.port inside each environment block:

```
environments {
    development {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
        host.address = "12.34.56.78"
        host.port = "8080"
        grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.serviceUrl = "${host.address}:${host.port}/${appName}/j_spring_cas_security_check"
        grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.afterLogoutUrl = "${casUrl}/logout?url=${host.address}:${host.port}/${appName}/"
    }
    test {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
        host.address = "http://staging.server.somewhere.com/"
        host.port = ""
        grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.serviceUrl = "${host.address}:${host.port}/${appName}/j_spring_cas_security_check"
        grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.afterLogoutUrl = "${casUrl}/logout?url=${host.address}:${host.port}/${appName}/"
    }
    production {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = false
        host.address = "http://www.production.com"
        host.port = ""
        grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.serviceUrl = "${host.address}:${host.port}/${appName}/j_spring_cas_security_check"
        grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.afterLogoutUrl = "${casUrl}/logout?url=${host.address}:${host.port}/${appName}/"
    }
 }
```

You can get rid of the host.address and host.port variables altogether:

```
environments {
    development {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
        grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.serviceUrl = "http://12.34.56.78:8080/${appName}/j_spring_cas_security_check"
        grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.afterLogoutUrl = "${casUrl}/logout?url=http://12.34.56.78:8080/${appName}/"
    }
    test {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
        grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.serviceUrl = "http://staging.server.somewhere.com/${appName}/j_spring_cas_security_check"
        grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.afterLogoutUrl = "${casUrl}/logout?url=http://staging.server.somewhere.com/${appName}/"
    }
    production {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = false
        grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.serviceUrl = "http://www.production.com/${appName}/j_spring_cas_security_check"
        grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.afterLogoutUrl = "${casUrl}/logout?url=http://www.production.com/${appName}/"
    }
 }
```